Capicatorjs addListener for mobile backButton not working on app's first page
I have an angular 14 and capacitors v6 android app project, In that app, I am trying to open a popup on mobile back button press,
In my login page (which is entry point of app) as I hit back button popup does not open, but as i hit login button of my loggin page the popup suddenly appears. The popup opens and closes fine on the after-login pages but not on the login page.
//Variable which will open a dialog as it will be true
dialogState: boolean = false;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   CapacitorApp.addListener('backButton', () => {
     this.dialogState = true;
   });
 }

 onNoClick() {
   this.dialogState = false;
 }

 onYesClick() {
   this.dialogState = false;
   CapacitorApp.exitApp();
 }

